# Search by spliting string in multiple columns of SQL table?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, full-text-search

I have a `Books` table:

```
Title                     Board    Class
----------------------------------------
Interactive English       CBSE       9
Interactive  Math         ICSE      10
Hindi                     CBSE       9
```

I have a search textbox in asp.net website. If user types in 
`"9 CBSE"` in textbox, my select query should return

```
Title                      Board    Class
-----------------------------------------
Interactive English        CBSE        9
Hindi                      CBSE        9
```

And if user types in `"9 English"` it should return

```
Title                      Board    Class
------------------------------------------
Interactive English        CBSE        9
```

So what should my select query be to match textbox value to all these three columns ?

Comment: It is out of the plan to have three different textboxes for the input?

Comment: is there any order to the search words?

Comment: What if user enters "9 E" should it find both English and CBSE or neither of them?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for Full Text Search. Look up that feature in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

I can not verify this because I have no access to a Sqlserver right now but this should work:

```
select
 *
from
 books
where
  patindex('%' + left(_textbox_contents_, charindex(' ') - 1) + '%',  Title + Board + Class) > 0 
  and  patindex('%' + substring(_textbox_contents_, charindex(' ') + 1) + '%',  Title + Board + Class) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can break up the string in c# before you send the query and create variables holding the parts e.g.:

string1 = "9"
string2 = "English"

Then you need to appened a '%' to each side giving you:

string1 = "%9%"
string2 = %English%"

Then pass the query as:

```
Select *
  from books
 where (title like string1
     or title like string2)
    or (board like string1
     or board like string2)
    or (class like string1
     or class like string2);
```

I figure splitting the search string up before sending the query is easier than trying to do it with SQL where you'll need to do a bunch of instrings and substrings.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this issue, we should plan how to attach the problem in hand.

1. We should extract from the search input the **Title or Board** values and **Number** value if it available.
2. We should construct our **SQL Query** in such order that it will match our extract value from `Title` or `Board` columns.
3. We should try to find a `Number` match in our **SQL Query** only if `Number` is indeed extracted (If it extracted than it has a value different from `null` or `Whitespace`).

**SearchInput:** Entity representing the search input values

```
public class SearchInput
{
    public string TitleOrBoard { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

**CreateSearchInput:** Transform the input string into the above entity.

Search if the first value in the string is a number. If the first value is a number than assign it to `Number` and remove the number from the input string.

```
public static SearchInput CreateSearchInput(string input)
{
    var inputSplitted = input.Trim().Split(new [] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    int number;

    string searchText = "";
    if (int.TryParse(inputSplitted.First(), out number))
    {
        searchText = String.Join(" ", inputSplitted.Skip(1));
    }

    var searchInput = new SearchInput()
    {
        Number = number.ToString(),
        TitleOrBoard = searchText
    };

    return searchInput;
}
```

**ConstructSearchQuery:** Building the SQLQuery based on the `SearchInput` entity values.

```
public static string ConstructSearchQuery(SearchInput searchInput)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM Books WHERE");
    sb.AppendFormat(" ([Title] LIKE '%{0}%' OR [Board] LIKE '%{0}%')", searchInput.TitleOrBoard);
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchInput.Number))
    {
        sb.AppendFormat(" OR Class = '%{0}%'", searchInput.Number);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

**Main function**

```
public static void Main()
{
    string input = "9 English";
    var searchInput = CreateSearchInput(input);
    string sqlQuery = ConstructSearchQuery(searchInput);
    Console.WriteLine("Search: Number[{0}] TitleOrBoard[{1}]", searchInput.Number, searchInput.TitleOrBoard);
    Console.WriteLine("SQL Query: {0}", sqlQuery);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Search: Number[9] TitleOrBoard[English]
SQL Query: SELECT * FROM Books WHERE ([Title] LIKE '%English%' OR [Board] LIKE '%English%') OR Class = '%9%'
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5IyeNR)

Comment: Actually Sir it will return English books from all classes including 9 class because or operator  .Could we get more accurate result i.e. only English books of class 9 ? Thanks

Comment: @RajnishSingh, Just change the `OR Class..` to `AND Class..`

Answer (score 0):

```
try this,

        declare @t table (Title  varchar(100), Board varchar(10),   Class int)
        declare @chk varchar(10)='9 English'
        insert into @t (Title, Board,   Class) values
        ('Interactive English','CBSE',9),
        ('Interactive  Math','ICSE',10),
        ('Hindi','CBSE',9)



select * from @t where  cast(Class as varchar(2)) +' '+Board  like '%' + @chk +'%' 
or Board +' '+cast(Class as varchar(2)) like '%' + @chk +'%' or

cast(Class as varchar(2)) +' '+case when charindex(' ', title)=0 then  
title else REverse(substring(reverse(title),1,charindex(' ', REVERSE(title))-1)) end 
like '%' +@chk +'%' or

case when charindex(' ', title)=0 then  
title else REverse(substring(reverse(title),1,charindex(' ', REVERSE(title))-1)) end +' '+cast(Class as varchar(2)) 
like '%' +@chk +'%'
```

Comment: Sir,Actually here are two problems :

Comment: both case it should work, please change @chk='9 CBSE' and try

Comment: But sir if the Value is 'CBSE 9' ?

Comment: then you need to add on more or or Board +' '+cast(Class as varchar(2)) like '%' + @chk +'%'

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to find all results where any of search keywords match at least one value this should work for you:

```
private string BuildQueryString(List<string> keywords)
{
    List<string> numbers = keywords.Where(keyword => keyword.All(Char.IsDigit))
                                   .ToList();

    List<string> words = keywords.Except(numbers)
                                 .Select(keyword => string.Format("('{0}')", keyword))
                                 .ToList();

    var queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    if (words.Count > 0)
    {
        queryBuilder.AppendFormat(@"
            CREATE TABLE #Keywords
            (
                Keyword NVARCHAR(MAX)
            )

            INSERT INTO #Keywords (Keyword)
            VALUES {0} ",

            string.Join(", ", words));
    }

    queryBuilder.AppendFormat(@"
        SELECT Title, Board, Class
        FROM Books ");

    string numbersFilter = string.Format("Class IN ({0})", string.Join(", ", numbers));
    string wordsFilter = @"EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1
                                   FROM #Keywords
                                   WHERE Title LIKE '%' + Keyword + '%'
                                      OR Board LIKE '%' + Keyword + '%')";

    if (numbers.Count > 0 && words.Count > 0)
    {
        queryBuilder.AppendFormat(@"
            WHERE {0} AND {1}", numbersFilter, wordsFilter);
    }
    else if (numbers.Count > 0)
    {
        queryBuilder.AppendFormat(@"
            WHERE {0}", numbersFilter);
    }
    else if (words.Count > 0)
    {
        queryBuilder.AppendFormat(@"
            WHERE {0}", wordsFilter);
    }

    return queryBuilder.ToString();
}
```

**Use case example:**

```
txtSearch.Text = "CBSE 9 MEH 23 Hey 90 N0 Word1";

List<string> keywords = txtSearch.Text
    .Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .ToList();

string queryString = BuildQueryString(keywords);
```

Your query string will return next query for this *Search Text*:

[image: Query]

And for the table content you gave in question description, result of this query will yield the next result:

[image: Table result]

Both of these records match on 9 in `Class` column and CBSE in `Board` column. You can change *ANDs* and *ORs* inside query builder if you want different behavior, but generally, this is what you asked for. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using a full text query you can give the end user a lot of flexibility with how they construct their search. Also you won't need to perform as much parsing of the search string, and the search is typically faster than using LIKE.

**1. Create the full text catalog and index.**

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [ftcat_Books] WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [Books] ([Title] LANGUAGE 'English', [Board] LANGUAGE 'English', [Class] LANGUAGE 'English')
KEY INDEX [PK_Books] ON ([ftcat_Books], FILEGROUP [PRIMARY])
WITH (CHANGE_TRACKING = AUTO, STOPLIST = OFF)
```

Your Books.Class column has to be varchar or nvarchar for this to work.

I recommend using no stoplists (`STOPLIST = OFF`) so that single digit numbers, like 9 in your example, are not ignored.

[More about accent sensitivity](https://markeboyle.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/sql-server-2008-full-text-indexing-accent-sensitivity/) (This example uses no accent sensitivity)

[More about change tracking](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1135/change-tracking-in-sql-server-full-text-search/) (This example uses change tracking)

**2. Convert user queries to boolean syntax.**

When a user types `9 CBSE` it will have to be converted to `"9" AND "CBSE"`. Each term must be surrounded in double quotes and separated by "AND". (You can also use OR, NOT, NEAR, and wildcards but I am not sure you need them in your case.)

Here's a simple way to convert to the boolean syntax you need using .NET regex (basically, replace each series of 1+ spaces with `" AND "` and surround the result with more double quotes):

```
// assume searchString = "9 CBSE"
string searchStringBoolean = "\"" + Regex.Replace(searchString, @"\s+", "\" AND \"") + "\"";
```

Keep in mind this is a very simple approach. You will need to consider what to do if the user already typed double quotes or AND in their search string.

**3. Run the full text query.**

```
-- @SearchStringBoolean is the boolean string created in step 2
SELECT TOP 100 Books.Title, Books.Board, Books.Class
FROM ContainsTable(Books, *, @SearchStringBoolean) as FullTextResults
join Books on FullTextResults.KEY = Books.Id
ORDER BY FullTextResults.RANK desc
```

This returns the top 100 matches with the best matches sorted first.